# jsonSchema2Pojo how to generate HashMap with String as key and value as another class generated using schema

Tags: json, pojo, jsonschema2pojo

I wanted to generate POJO classes from json schema, in which one of the attribute in the generated class should be a map of type - Map<String, List>. Here CustomClass should be a class generated using jsonnSchema2pojo plugin.

How do we achieve this in schema? How does the schema looks like?

Comment: Kindly suggest some solution..

Answer (score 0):

Search for Extensions > javaType on https://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ - And I am sure you can do that.